# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 192: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm new to Python and going through Automate the Boring Stuff, chapter 7.  I'm running the program Phone Number and Email Address Extractor and keep getting the following error, "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 192: invalid start byte".  I'm copying to the clipboard [this page here](https://www.nostarch.com/automatestuff/) as a start off.

Here's my code.  Can anyone help as I'm a bit lost as to what to do to  get the program to run?

```
#! python 3
# phoneAddEmail.py - Finds phone numbers and email addresses on the clipboard
import pyperclip, re

phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?                # area code
(\s|-|\.)?                        # separator
(\d{3})                           # first 3 digits
(\s|-|\.)                         # separator
(\d{4})                           # last 4 digits
(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?    # extension
)''', re.VERBOSE)

#TODO: Create email regex.
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+      # username
@                      # @ symbol
[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+         # domain name
(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})      # dot-something
)''', re.VERBOSE)

#TODO: Find matches in clipboard text.
text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches = []
for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
    phoneNum = '-'.join([groups[1], groups[3], groups[5]])
    if groups[8] != '':
        phoneNum += ' x' + groups[8]
    matches.append(phoneNum)
for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0])


#TODO: Copy results to the clipboard.
if len(matches) > 0:
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
    print('Copied to clipboard:')
    print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('No phone numbers or email addresses found.')
```

Comment: I also worked through that book, and did this same exercise.  I tested your code on the site you linked to, and it ran fine for me with Python 3.5 IDLE.  Result was no numbers/emails found.  Your problem seems to be coming from somewhere else, but I don't know where.  What are you using to run your code?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5 IDLE and using a Mac osx system.

Comment: Ok.  I'm on Win7.  Unfortunately, all I can say is that the code runs fine here.  Maybe you can try testing your code on different text.  Whatever it is causing you this problem, it's certainly beyond the scope of the Automate book.

Comment: Which line throws the error? Please include the whole stacktrace when asking a question. Cheers

Comment: Here is the full error. Line 24 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/phoneAddEmail.py", line 24, in <module>
    text = str(pyperclip.paste())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyperclip/clipboards.py", line 22, in paste_osx
    return stdout.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 1693: invalid start byte

Comment: So,  I got this to work by going into Terminal and typing idle3.  I also have 2.7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to write simple application for MacOS, which changes clipboard:  paste -> alter -> copy back.
It works well from PyCharm but failed when I packed it with py2app.

Since pyperclip uses external program for handling clipboard, I added environment logging:

LOG: running from PyCharm:

```
LANG --> 'en_US.UTF-8'
LANGUAGE --> 'en_US.UTF-8'
LC_ALL --> 'en_US.UTF-8'
LC_CTYPE --> ''
PYTHONIOENCODING --> 'UTF-8'
```

LOG: running from py2app bundle:

```
LC_CTYPE --> 'en_US.UTF-8'
```

so I've patched os.eniron:

```
def init_env():
    def set_env_var(k, v):
        os.environ[k] = v
        logging.debug('set %s = %r' % (k, v))

    set_env_var("LANG", "en_US.UTF-8")
    set_env_var("LANGUAGE", "en_US.UTF-8")
    set_env_var("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
    set_env_var("LC_CTYPE", "")
    set_env_var("PYTHONIOENCODING", "UTF-8")
```

and py2app now works fine.